# Lo Stivale italiano

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Il termine "stivale" viene stesso usato in riferimento alla morfologia del territorio italiano.

[Stivale](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stivale/): (Treccani.it)

> - In senso fig., per antonomasia, ***lo Stivale, l’Italia,*** così detta per la sua forma geografica che somiglia a quella di uno stivale: Goti e Vandali ... venuti a manomettere, a vituperare e a imbarbarire il nostro bellissimo e gloriosissimo Stivale (Baretti),

L'espressione viene, ad esempio, spesso usata in riferimento alle condizioni atmosferiche:

> - [Maltempo lungo tutto lo stivale](https://www.google.it/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=pioggia%20lungo%20tuttp%20lo%20stivale%20&oq=pioggia%20lungo%20tuttp%20lo%20stivale%20&gs_l=tablet-gws.3..30i10.1735.8583.0.8909.33.31.1.1.1.0.341.4657.0j27j3j1.31.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..1.26.3585.IcSn-a1-oqw#q=maltempo%20lungo%20lo%20stivale)

Mi chiedo se questa espressione abbia avuto origine nella poesia (risorgimentale ad esempio, quindi con riferimento all'Italia come unico territorio) o se sia solo un'espressione comune 
che si è diffusa con la diffusione delle prime mappe geografiche.

Answer (score 5):

L'espressione è senza dubbio antecedente al periodo Risorgimentale. Una rapida ricerca in Google Books ha prodotto il [*Saggio di congetture su i terremoti del dottore Cristofano Sarti*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MAMR9frHaGQC&pg=PA229&dq=%22stivale%20d%27%20italia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAlsHFxoTLAhUIdD4KHbR_BssQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22stivale%20d%27%20italia%22&f=false) del 1783

> Giova anche farsi un'idea della situazione della suddetta provincia della Calabria. [...] Il pezzo meridionale forma ciò, che chiamasi Metutasio, e punta del piede del famoso Stivale d'Italia.

Sospetto che l'uso risalga a molto più indietro di così, almeno fino al tardo medioevo, ma le limitazioni di Google books mi impediscono una ricerca più approfondita.

Inoltre vale la pena di notare che il riferimento all'Italia come unico territorio (anche se non come entità politica) risale al periodo romano ed è utilizzato ininterrotamente da allora sino ad oggi (vedasi, ad esempio, *Italia mia, benché il parlar sia indarno* del Petrarca).